# Linking Nvidia's Cg framework statically in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, nvidia, cg

10 billion kudos for life to anyone who can figure this one out.

Nvidia only provides a standard framework for Cg, which I cannot figure how I can link statically.  I need to link it statically because it's for a plugin.

Is there any way at all this can be done?

Comment: How are you distributing the plugin? You can include the Cg framework as a private framework if your plugin is a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cg compiler to compile the shader to the assembly, and then load the assembly using opengl functions. Then you do not need to have the Cg framework on the system using your application.